# Can anyone tell me what kind of mount this Rokinon lens has (Konica AR or Minolta)?

Tags: lens-mount, lens-adapter, old-lenses

I recently bought this lens and I am looking to adapt it to a Nikon D3300 and i was wondering if anyone could tell me what the mount of the lens is.
Thank you :)[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a Contax/Yashica (C/Y) mount. From the [WY Cameras identification guide](https://wycameras.com/blogs/news/35mm-slr-lens-mount-identification-guide-1),

> To identify them visually, it’s a similar situation to Minolta MD lenses – look for the position of the notch cut out of one of the bayonets. On C/Y lenses, it’s on the left of the bayonet.
>
> [image: C/Y mount]
> <sup>Image of C/Y lens mount. From [wycameras.com](https://wycameras.com/blogs/news/35mm-slr-lens-mount-identification-guide-1)</sup>

Specifically, because of the D-shaped fixed pin next to the notched tab on the right, your lens appears to be made for Yashica bodies. I believe the position of this pin communicates maximum aperture of the lens to the camera body. Source: [discussion at photrio.com](https://www.photrio.com/forum/threads/zeiss-lenses-for-contax-yashica-mount-problem-with-one-piece.164434/print)

In order to adapt it to a Nikon F-mount body, because the C/Y mount registration distance (also known as flange focus distance) is shorter than the F-mount registration distance, you will need an adapter with a corrective lens in it. These types of adapters tend to reduce the image quality.

See also, [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000/11924)

Comment: It probably is C/Y mount, but the extra "D-shaped" stationary pin just inside the notch on the photo in the OP worries me a bit.

Comment: @MichaelC Yeah, I wondered about that. I think it's for Yashica bodies, to let them know the maximum aperture of the lens. See: https://www.photrio.com/forum/threads/zeiss-lenses-for-contax-yashica-mount-problem-with-one-piece.164434/print (warning, _painfully_ slow loading of this page)